# Java Split string to numbers

Tags: java

Hello I have a programme where you type in different commands. The only command I have at the moment is ping command. You type ping followed by your IP address.

example: `ping 192.167.2.1`

I want to get a result from this ping so I do this:

```
String ip = ""+l6+l7+l8+l9+l10+l11+l12+l13+l14+l15+l16;
String pingResult = "";

String pingCmd = "ping " + ip;

try {
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        pingResult += inputLine;
    }

    in.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

When I press a key the key value is stored in a string.

If `l1` is equal to `null`, then the value gets stored in `l1`,
if `l1` is not null and `l2` is null then the next key that is pressed is stored in `l2` and so on.

The maximum amount of keys you can press is 20. when you press enter all the strings are put together to form one big string. I want to be able to split that big string and take away the letters and leave the numbers. How can I do this.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provided an example of an output as you seek it

Comment: Why bother trying to validate your ping command?  If you pass a bad ping command to your Process, then p.getErrorStream() would have information for you.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all alphabets and leave only numbers :

```
ip = ip.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this :

```
ip = ip.replaceAll("[\\D&&[^\\.]]", "");
```

It will remove every non digit character except '.' which I believe you will need to form a correct IP ( something that you missed in the description).

Comment: In other words `replaceAll("[^\\d.]","")`?